# How to create a Python 3 environment that has only standard lib, no extra packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv

I'm trying to test how a package that I've created installs on a machine with a base Python 3 install, meaning no additional packages have been installed via pip, easy_install, etc.

How do I setup a virtual environment that acts like a clean install of Python 3? If I create a `pipenv` or `virtualenv`, then list all my installed packages, the 30 or so that I have are all still there. How can I make a Python environment that behaves like a brand new install of Python and has no extra packages?

This is in Raspberry Pi OS which has only one user, so using the `--user` flag in `pip install --user` might as well be a global install. I considered creating a new `pipenv` then `pip uninstall`ing everything, but am worried that will break something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you *activate* the virtual environment `virtualenv` created? Because if you don't, the virtual environment doesn't *do* anything. If you activated it, `python3 -mpip list` should show only a couple installed packages (e.g. `setuptools`, `pip`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With virtualenv you would do :

```
virtualenv myenv -p python3.8
```

This would create a virtual environment in the myenv directory with python3.8 and the standard library only. You would activate this by doing

```
source myenv/bin/activate.sh
```

If you are using virtualenvwrapper, then you create the virtual environment by doing:

```
mkvirtualenv myenv -p python3.8
```

and activate it by doing:

```
workon myenv
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I am not a virtualenv user, however here is what I could suggest if you have conda installed:
`conda create -n myenv python=3.6`

Where myenv is the name of your environment and 3.6 the python version.

You can then enable the environment by doing:
`conda activate myenv`

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep looking for `pipenv` solutions, but this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

A pipenv solution to this would be to create the virtual environment by specifying the version of python you wish to use.

```
pipenv --python <version>
```

This will create a virtual environment with the specified version of python and nothing else.

e.g.

```
pipenv --python 3    # Will use the first python 3 version found on your machine
pipenv --python 3.9  # Will use python 3.9 if it is installed on your machine
```

This works with `--python 2` and `--python 2.x` also.

https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#specifying-versions-of-python

Comment: Added this despite the year gap as I came across this question when searching for the same answer and OP mentioned looking for a `pipenv` solution.